# MS Report Viewer 2008 Export to excel merged cells problem

Tags: c#, excel, reportviewer2008

We are using MS Report Viewer for exporting Reports to Excel, now we have a problem when trying to sort data, its reporting error that there are merged cells and it can't be sorted. So is there a way to disable cell merging when exporting to excel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no way to turn this off. However, I only notice it being a problem when I use page headers or page footers. This is why often times I'll make page headers and footers optional in my reports to avoid the Excel merge cell issue.

Comment: I don't have headers nor footers, but problem persists